# Reading email body with encoding ISO-8859-1

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit for reading some email's body content by using IMAP.

Some of these emails come with content-type `text/plain` and charset `ISO-8859-1` which causes that my code replaces some Latin characters `á é í ó ú` and apparently also `CR` and `LF` by weird chars such as `=E1` `=FA` `=F3` `=`...

```
var body = message.BodyParts.OfType<BodyPart>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.IsMimeType("text", "plain"));
var bodyText = (TextPart)folder.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, body);
var bodyContent = bodyText.Text;
```

There is no problem when opening these emails with email clients such as Thunderbird or Outlook. They are showing these chars as they are. I want to be able to retrieve these Latin chars.

I've tried with some encoding options with no success.

```
var bodyContent = bodyText.GetText(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII); 
var bodyContent = bodyText.GetText(System.Text.Encoding.UTF-8);
```

Comment: Normally you don't need to decode quoted-printable encoded content yourself, but my guess is that the client that sent this message encoded the content using the quoted-printable encoding but did not set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't need to decode quoted-printable encoded content yourself, but my guess is that the client that sent this message encoded the content using the quoted-printable encoding but did not set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header properly.

I would probably change your code to something more like this:

```
// figure out which body part we need
var body = message.BodyParts.OfType<BodyPartText>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.IsMimeType("text", "plain"));

// download the body part we need
var bodyText = (TextPart)folder.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, body);

// If it's encoded using quoted-printable we'll need to decode it first.
// To do so, we'll need the charset.
//
// The reason I would get it from the `bodyText.ContentType` is because
// this will work even if you used MessageSummaryItems.Body instead of
// MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure.
var charset = bodyText.ContentType.Charset;

// Decodes the content by using QuotedPrintableDecoder from MimeKit library.
var bodyContent = DecodeQuotedPrintable(bodyText.Content, charset);


// The main changes I'm making to this function compared to what you have is
// using the stream/filter interfaces rather than using the low-level decoder
// directly. You can do it either way, but if you continue using your
// method - I would recommend using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() rather than 
// Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes() because UTF-8 can handle all strings while
// ASCII cannot.
static string DecodeQuotedPrintable (IMimeContent content, string charset)
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream ()) {
        using (filtered = new FilteredStream (output)) {
            // add a quoted-printable decoder
            filtered.Add (DecoderFilter.Create (ContentEncoding.QuotedPrintable));

            // pump the content through the decoder
            content.DecodeTo (filtered);

            // flush the filtered stream
            filtered.Flush ();
        }

        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding (charset);

        return encoding.GetString (output.GetBuffer (), 0, (int) output.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried your modification but the charset retrieved from the `bodyText.ContentType` is `null`.

Comment: However I'm able to retrieve it successfully from both  `body.ContentType.Charset` and `body.ContentType.CharsetEncoding`. But `ContenType` from `bodyText` seems to be `null`.

Comment: That shouldn't ever happen unless either the IMAP server is broken or the message is broken (or both?). What is the charset in your case? is it "us-ascii" or "utf-8" or something else? I'm guessing if it's one of those 2, it might just be the IMAP server going with a default. What do the MIME part headers look like? (use `bodyText.WriteTo(fileName)` to save it to disk)

Comment: This is the headers i can see once saved to disk:
`MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`

Comment: Something isn’t right... if those headers exist, then MimeKit should be finding the charsets and quoted-printable encoding values correctly. Any chance you could share the IMAP protocol log with me? You can X-out the actual message text, but I’ll need the actual MIME structure of the message unmodified if possible. When you create the ImapClient, just pass new ProtocolLogger (“imap.log”) to the ctor and it will save a log file.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that when MailKit requests the headers (`BODY.PEEK[1.1.MIME]`), the response has a blank line before the start of the headers and a blank line indicates the end of the headers (and it is legal for a MIME part to have no headers by starting with `"\r\n"`) and so MailKit defaults the MIME part to the default headers for MIME which is `"Content-Type: text/plain"`. Dovecot (IMAP server) must have a parser that tries to work around mail client bugs like this by ignoring that blank line if what comes next look like headers.

Comment: BTW, delete the link in your comment as it accidentally exposes your account password. I should have warned about X-ing that out as well.

Comment: I realized that it was encoded in base64. There is no problem with the link. It expired after 1 download.

Comment: So, I suppose there is nothing i can do in the code to geit it working as the bug resides at the IMAP server. Isn't it?

Comment: It's actually not an IMAP server bug (Dovecot is a really good server btw), it's really a bug in the sending client. That said, yea, unfortunately, MimeKit/MailKit do not currently have a work-around for this sort of bug. This is a complicated type of bug to work around due to having to be able to re-serialize it so that digital signatures can be verified (if the message is signed). :-\

Comment: Ok, Then i still continue getting the charset from `body.ContentType.Charset`. Thanks for  your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

The message body is encoded using [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). 
You have to decode it first.

In MailKit it should be the [DecodeTo method](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MimeContent_DecodeTo.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and pointing me out in the right direction. I could finally solve it with  [QuotedPrintableDecoder](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Encodings_QuotedPrintableDecoder.htm) from [Mimekit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit)

Answer (score 1):

I could finally get it working by using [QuotedPrintableDecoder](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Encodings_QuotedPrintableDecoder.htm) from [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library.

```
var body = message.BodyParts.OfType<BodyPart>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentType.IsMimeType("text", "plain"));
// If it's encoded using quoted-printable we'll need to decode it first. To do so, we'll need the charset.
var charset = body.ContentType.Charset;
var bodyText = (TextPart)folder.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, body);
// Decodes the content by using QuotedPrintableDecoder from MimeKit library.
var bodyContent = DecodeQuotedPrintable(bodyText.Text, charset);


static string DecodeQuotedPrintable (string input, string charset)
{
    var decoder = new QuotedPrintableDecoder ();
    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (input);
    var output = new byte[decoder.EstimateOutputLength (buffer.Length)];
    int used = decoder.Decode (buffer, 0, buffer.Length, output);
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding (charset);
    return encoding.GetString (output, 0, used);
}
```